# Python dynamic import and __all__

Tags: python, dynamic, import, loading

I am facing a behaviour that I don't understand even through I feel it is a very basic question...

Imagine you have a python package `mypackage` containing a module `mymodule` with 2 files `__init__.py` and  `my_object.py`. Last file contains a class named `MyObject`.

I am trying to right an automatic import within the `__init__.py` that is an equivalent to :

**__init__.py**

```
__all__ = ['MyObject']
from my_object import MyObject
```

in order to be able to do:

```
from mypackge.mymodule import MyObject
```

I came up with a solution that fill **all** with all classes' names. It uses `__import__` (also tried the `importlib.import_module()` method) but when I try to import `MyObject` from the `mymodule`, it keeps telling me:

```
ImportError: cannot import name MyObject
```

Here is the script I started with :

```
classes = []
for module in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
    if module != '__init__.py' and module[-3:] == '.py':

        module_name = module[:-3]
        import_name = '%s.%s' % (__name__, module_name)

        # Import module here! Looking for an equivalent to 'from module import MyObject' 
        # importlib.import_module(import_name)  # Same behaviour
        __import__(import_name, globals(), locals(), ['*'])

        members = inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[import_name], lambda member: inspect.isclass(member) and member.__module__.startswith(__name__) )

        names = [member[0] for member in members]
        classes.extend(names)

__all__ = classes
```

Can someone help me on that point ?

Many thanks,

Comment: You can just filter `vars(mod).items()` instead of using `inspect`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to assign attributes on the module: `globals().update(members)`.